# Can pivot positions be occupied by something other than pivots?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that "pivot is a nonzero number in a pivot position that is used as needed to create zeros via row operations", but today a TA just said: "pivot positions need not contain pivots".

I am a little bit confused about the last claim. Can pivot positions be occupied by something other than pivots?!

Answer (score 0):

A pivot position is just that, a position.

For example:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\square&2\\
2&\square\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

both of the squares are pivot positions, but they are not themselves pivots since the first column has a $2$ as its final entry, and not a 0.

All pivot positions are occupied by $1$'s but these are not pivots
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
1&1\\
\end{array}
\right).$$

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but we can always safely say pivot positions of echelon-form matrices are always occupied by pivots, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe that would be correct. Your TA saying "pivot positions need not contain pivots" is probably in reference to the cases I provided, that in general there need not be a pivot in any given column (think the zero matrix). In particular, you may have a pivot position, and not have a pivot, take for example $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&\square&0\\ 0&0&\square\\\end{array}\right)$$
which has at most two pivot positions, but depending on what the squares are, may not have pivots.